# Problem adding vertical scroll bar to iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, scrollbar

I have added a vertical scroll bar to my iFrame which is created through JS. The iFrame contents are set dynamically i.e user can add fields to this iFrame.when the height of the frame goes beyond the limit the upper fields get hidden.how can this problem be delt with.?

Comment: Some code sample would help a lot...

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you are looking for. All i could understand is you are dealing with an iframe whose size changes dynamically. So why don't you try auto scrolling.

Set your attribute `scrolling="auto"`. Please correct me if i wrongly understood your question.